# Who is Seymour saying "once lived in this metropolis?"

Tags: final-fantasy

In this [scene](https://m.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=nPU0h69fY2g), Seymour Guado shows Yuna's party the Zanarkand of 1,000 years ago, via a holographic projection, based on memories from the Farplane. At the 1:01 mark in the video, he mysteriously mentions "*She* once lived in this metropolis." Yuna asks, "She who?" The camera zooms in on Seymour, but he doesn't answer.

To whom is he referring? Are we ever told, and why is it important to the story?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the she that Seymour is referring to is Lady Yunalesca. You do end up meeting her at a significant point in the story

Spoilers below

> Lady Yunalesca was the daughter of Yu Yevon, who was the creator of Sin. Yunalesca was the first summoner to bring forth the Calm, sacrificing her husband Zaon to do so. Since that time waits in the ruins of Zanarkan an unsent. Her task is to explain the price for the final Aeon to summoners on the final step of their pilgrimages. In order to defeat Sin and bring the Calm, one of the summoner's guardians must be sacrificed and become the next Sin. Yuna rejects this offer and the party defeats Yunalesca.

Comment: What is the basis for believing this? Is it revealed to the player at some point and I just missed it? (I've played through to the end)

Comment: I guess it's mostly process of elimination. I don't remember the full context of this scene, but Yunalesca is the only "she" from old Zanarkand in the game from what I remember. If that's true, then who else could he be talking about?

Comment: @JohnWu Note also that immediately after Seymour says says, "She once lived in this metropolis," the "camera" switches to Auron, who softly scoffs.  Given what happened between Auron and Yunalesca...

Comment: I don’t disagree. I am just wondering how I could ever have known that. I was guessing it was Seymour’s mother, since she’s an Aeon, but but the timelines are all wrong.

Comment: "[Seymour](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Seymour_Guado) believes, as many do, that Sin is eternal and sees death as a release from the sorrow of life" - Yunalesca is Seymour's hero. She was the first person to defeat and become Sin, becoming a 'savior'. The shift to Auron is because it was "she" who mortally wounded him.

Comment: @JohnWu - I've been trying to nail this plot down for the last 18 years; don't feel bad. I thought it should've been his mother too, because he blames Sin for her death. But I guess he got over that and wants to be like his mom now, who ironically is no longer on board with the whole deal.

Comment: If it helps anyone with the plot, here's a series of articles by one of my favorite game journalists about FFX https://www.shamusyoung.com/twentysidedtale/?p=32341

Comment: @JohnWu after Yuna says "she, who?" the cutscene shifts to inside Lady Yunalescas room, with her sitting on the bed, and Yuna says "Lady Yunalesca!". This is supposed to indicate that this is the "she" they are talking about (why would Seymour suddenly cut from Zanarkand to some completely unrelated woman?). It's a little muddled because of the shift from CG to in-engine graphics, but they're still viewing the same recording of Zanarkand (as evidenced by Yunalesca walking through them) as they were at the start of the scene.